# CSS precedence order? My lecture slides are correct or not?

Tags: html, css, operator-precedence

I've noticed that there are a couple of similar questions and answers at SO already, but let me clarify my specific question here first:

I've got lecture slides which states like this:

http://mindinscription.net/webapp/csstest/precedence.PNG

To be frank, I haven't heard of this rule of css precedence myself, and I googled to find something with similar topic but not quite like that : [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

To have a test myself, I've made a test page on my own server [here](http://mindinscription.net/webapp/csstest/)

After running it on FireFox 3.6.3, I am sure it does not show the way as it should be, according to the statement in lecture slides:

- imported stylesheet ? am I doing it wrong? I cannot see its effect using FireBug
- it says that embedded stylesheet has a higher precedence over linked/imported stylesheets, however, it doesn't work, if I put the linked/imported tag AFTER that.
- inline style vs html attributes ? I've got an image where I firstly set its inline style to control the width and height, then use direct html attributes width/height to try modifying that, but failed...

Below is the source code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #target
        {
            border : 2px solid green;
            color  : green;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./linked.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target">A targeted div tag on page.</div>

    <img src="cat.jpg" alt="" style="width : 102px; height : 110px;" width="204px" height="220px" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Can any experienced CSS guys help me figure out if the slide is correct or not?**

Frankly speaking, I am puzzled myself, as I can clearly see some other "incorrect" statements here and there amongst the slides, such as JavaScript is on client-side (how about server-side JavaScript?) and "Embedded styles are in the head section of a web page
"(what the heck? I am not allowed to put it inside the body tag?)

Sorry about this silly question, the exam is on TOMORROW, and I now see a lot of things to think about :)

Comment: @Nick Yuck, you don't want to touch that slide then... Did you mean: *amok*? `</spellcheck>` ;)

Comment: That's a JPEG picture of 933 KB with only black text on a yellow background? You definitely should use [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Comparison_with_JPEG) for that!

Comment: Your slide definitely needs an adjustment, the CSS style determining your background color has run a mock*, spelling eludes me still :(

Comment: @Marcel Korpel : Thanks for this, I just used MS paint to get the pic but forgot to change it to PNG :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with imported stylesheets they mean stylesheets embedded using [the `@import` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import).

Second, a few lines below that explanation in the CSS 2.1 spec there's an explanation of the [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade). Other parts of [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) might be useful for your exam, too. Good luck.

*Update:* A bit of [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+cascading+order) resulted in:

- http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/topics/cascade.htm
- http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css
- http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_4.html
- http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=2795D

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the links, definitely helpful.

Comment: I always forget to put the + among keywords :( Thanks for the links, now I can tell why the slide would get such a weird statement to me :) I hope in exam it wouldn't get too much on this tricky topic.

Comment: @Michael: the +? You mean when doing a Google search? You can just enter spaces in the search field.

Answer (score 2):

- The properties by `<style></style>` are being reassigned by the selector in `linked.css`.
- There is no element with `id="div"` for `imported.css`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. But I am happy to see it doesn't change the final appearance of the page. Yeah, I am thinking the "precedence" is actually whichever comes the "latest" applies. But... that is not in the slide :(